# Common Flutter Error (missing required argument)

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am new to flutter and I was trying to test some liblaries.
But unfortunately when I run this code, I get error:

*error mesage:*

```
error G4A9793AD: The value 'null' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Key' because 'Key' is not nullable.
```

[error image url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gEqfD.png)

```
...some code...
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          home: MainPage(title: 'Flutter Convex BottomBar Sample'),
        );
      }
    }
 
class MainPage extends StatefulWidget {
  MainPage({required Key key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);
...some code...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't pass a value of `null` to the `key` parameter because it's non-nullable (can't have `null` as value) to mark it as nullable you should add `?`:

```
MainPage({required Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);
```

Anyway I think that's not what you want because its also not allowed. Simply drop the `required` keyword or pass a valid key to it:

```
MainPage({Key key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);
```

Answer (score 2):

Either remove the `Key key` variable from `MainPage` by deleting it,

OR just provide a key

```dart
home: MainPage(title: 'Flutter Convex BottomBar Sample',key : Key('homepage'),),
```